# Nodejs mongodb API performance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, performance

I want to create an API which will query users in my mongodb and returns the data of all users. For each user i need to perform additional query to get count in 2 other schema as below:

```
const getUsersSummary = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const users = await User.fetch();
    const usersWithCount = await Promise.all(
      users.map(async (user) => {
        let tests;
        let enrollments;
        try {
          tests = await Test.countDocuments(
            { user: user._id }
          );
          enrollments = await Enrollment.countDocuments(
            { user: user._id }
          );
        } catch (e) {
          tests = 0;
          enrollments = 0;
        }
        return {
          _id: user._id,
          name: user.name,
          address: user.address,
          tests: tests,
          enrollments: enrollments,
        };
      })
    );
    return res.json({
      users: usersWithCount,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

I want to know if this is a good way to do it.

The code works. But i am concerned about the performance and load it will put on my server.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might consider use the MongoDB aggregation framework. You can combine user data with trial and registration data using the $lookup operator to join the user data with the tests and enrollments data, and then use the $group operator to get the count of tests and enrollments for each user. This will reduce the number of database queries and improve the performance of your API.

```
    const aggregate = User.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "tests",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "user",
          as: "tests"
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "enrollments",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "user",
          as: "enrollments"
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 1,
          name: 1,
          address: 1,
          tests: { $size: "$tests" },
          enrollments: { $size: "$enrollments" }
        }
      }
    ]);
    const usersWithCount = await aggregate.exec();
    return res.json({
      users: usersWithCount,
    });
```

Comment: You could also add pagination or using a query parameter to limit the number of users returned in a single API call